# How to monkeypatch method that's deep inside a library for only a single module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

I want to monkeypatch the `assert_fingerprint` method defined for urllib3 in this file: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/main/src/urllib3/util/ssl_.py

However, we're not using urllib3 directly. We're using the requests library, which uses urllib3 below the surface. Additionally, I only want a single class in my code to have the "monkeypatched version" when using the requests interface, everywhere else in my code the normal behavior is expected. This is for production use, not for (unit)testing usage.

There's a lot of information out and about on how to patch or monkeypatch, but they're usually very tailored to specific classes that can be imported directly. Would I have to track down the entire import-chain here starting from requests to get down to this file?

Comment: Sound like an X Y problem. What original problem are you trying to fix with this?

Comment: If you need to monkey-patch certificate fingerprint checking, it sounds like you're dealing with an invalid certificate? How about disabling SSL certificate checking in general, which I believe can be done from the requests API?

Comment: I'm dealing with a specific use-case where multiple certificates need to be accepted based on their fingerprint and not only their CA's. Disabling checking is the exact opposite of what we want to do.